# Nested HTML5 templates with data binding

Tags: javascript, html, templates

So I have been trying to create a really simple version of polymer, just to learn a little more about web components and data binding. I have found this fiddle that shows simple data binding with HTML5 templates http://jsfiddle.net/falafelsoftware/8fa8g (only works in supported browsers)

HTML:

```
<template>
   <ul>
     <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
   </ul>
</template>
<div id="result"></div>
```

JS:

```
var template = document.querySelector('template').content;
var shadow   = document.querySelector('#result').createShadowRoot();
var clone    = document.importNode(template, true);
shadow.appendChild(clone);
```

The above code will output the unordered list into the page as you can see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k40nbuq5/1/

But what i really want is to be able to have a nested template with data bindings so i would like my template to look like this:

```
<template>
   <ul>
     <template repeat="{{items}}>
        <li><a href="">{{name}}</a></li>
     </template>
   </ul>
</template>
<div id="result"></div>
```

If you check out the first fiddle it applies a property called "model" to the template and it seems to automatically know what to do with the data binding. However I am unable to achieve the same effect with a nested template. So I tried the following but no luck:

```
var template = document.querySelector('template');
var child    = template.querySelector('template');

child.model = [
   { name: 'Home' }
];

var shadow   = document.querySelector('#result').createShadowRoot();
var clone    = document.importNode(template.content, true);
shadow.appendChild(clone);
```

The model property exists on the nested template but it does not do anything to render the  contents. I have tried a few other ways, but have been unsuccessful so far.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `var child = template.content.querySelector('template');`?